# What are initialized first, primitives or objects?

Tags: java, object, static-members

```
class A{
public final static int num = 0;
public final static B instance = null;
}
```

I have heard that class members are initialized first. So in this code, what is initialized first and does Java have an order in which variables are initialized?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `B instance` is a reference, not an object.

Comment: Which means there isn't as much difference with a primitive as it might appear. A reference is just a 4-byte or 8 byte pointer you can't manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will initialized in the order you write them in the code. First int will be initialized followed by B

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you heard that but I do believe they are initialized in the order in which they are written.
Check the 
[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>   **in textual order**, as though they were a single block.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final static int num = 0;
public final static B instance = null;
```

Both the statements involve equal/equivalent effort on JVM's part. The second statement just creates a *null* reference, and not an actual *new* object. The reference is typically a (32/64 bit) value *depending on the VM and the platform*. So, I'd say the JVM will execute them in the order they appear.

[§12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) JLS:

> The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces
>   whose values are compile-time constant expressions (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1,
>   §13.4.9, §15.28).
>
> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>   in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the variable a *static* variable, so they are basically class variable and are created at the moment class is loaded.

Class loading happens at once, so there is nothing that which one is created first. JVM simply create them one by one, may be in order of declaration. 
Both `num` and `instance` are a set of 32-bit/64 bit data; with only difference is that `num` values to numeric 0; while instance is value is an address.